# Hiding in foreach loop

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, mysql

I am getting json in "data" and passing it in for loop.  Onclick of buy button, it goes to the App function. On success I need to hide the buy button and display the download label.

My problem is onclick of 1st buy button, download link for both the buttons appear.
Ideally oneclick of first buy button, buy button should be hidden and download label should appear. similarly oneclick of second buy button, buy button should be hidden and download label should appear.

How do I get particular id of each button so that I can hide one at a time?

Please help me out

```
function (data)
    {   
        var Class ='';
        for (var i=0; i <data.length;i++)
        { 
            Class += '<div name="buy\''+data[i].id+'\'" class="btn btn-primary btn-small" onclick="buy(\''+data[i].identifier+'\',\''+data[i].id+'\',\''+data[i].url +'\'); return false;" href=""></div><div class="download\''+data[i].id+'\'" id="download">D<span style="font-size:15px"></span></div>';
        }
        return Class;
    }


App = function(identifier, app_id, url) {
    $.ajaxSetup({
            data : {
                csrf_test_name : $.cookie('csrf_cookie_name')
            }
        });
        var jqxhr = $.post(SITE_URL + 'admin/appstore/purchaseApp', {
            identifier : identifier,
            ap_id : ap_id
        }).done(function(data1) {
            obj = JSON.parse(data1);
            bootbox.alert(obj.status, obj.label);
            $("#download").html('<a href='+download_url+app_id+'>Download!</a>');




        });
    };
```

it is for loop am using.. am passing '; now how do I hide buy id? $("#buys"+"'"+data[i].id+"'").hide(); is this the right way? It gives me error

Comment: Where is the forEach loop?

Comment: sorry, it is for loop am using..
am passing 

<div id="buys\''+data[i].id+'\'" onclick="App(\''+data[i].identifier+'\',\''+data[i].id+'\',\''+data[i].url +'\'); return false;" href=""></div><div class="download" id="download"><span style="font-size:15px"></span></div>';

now how do I hide buy id?

$("#buys"+"'"+data[i].id+"'").hide();
is this the right way? It gives me error

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

if you look at the actual markup generated in Class, you will see that your buy buttons don't have an id at all. perhaps something like

```
Class += '<div id="buy-button-'+data[i].id+'" name="...
```

Now you have a unique id on each button. The next part of your problem is knowing which button to remove after a successful Ajax call. You will need to include that in the data1, returned from the server. For the sake of argument, let's say the server returns the value in your data1 object as `app_id`. Then all you need to do is

```
jQuery('#buy-button-'+data1.app_id).hide();
```

Slightly off-topic, I'm not too keen on the way you're using single quotes in the buttons' name attributes, either, but I don't think that's relevant here.